# trying to format date variable with moment and pass it to datetimepicker which results indeprecation warning

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I am trying to format date variable and pass it to eonasdan datetimepicker for angular but no matter what I try to do I get

> Deprecation warning: moment construction falls back to js Date. This is discouraged and will be removed in upcoming major release. Please refer to https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407 for more info.
>   Arguments:

below are my tryouts:

date from ajax - Wed, 05 Jul 2017 00:00:00 GMT

```
/*example1*/
angular.forEach(tickets, function(value, key){
    $scope.startDate = new Date(value.start_date);
    $scope.endDate = new Date(value.end_date);
});

/*example2*/
angular.forEach(tickets, function(value, key){
    $scope.startDate = moment(startDate, "YYYY-MM-DD");
    $scope.endDate = moment(value.end_date, "YYYY-MM-DD");
});
```

here are datetimepicker options

```
$scope.calendarWidgetOptions = {
   format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
   minDate: moment().startOf('d')
};
```

I tried other stuff but can not make it work, and get rid of deprecation warning hence date is now visible in some browsers/timezones.

Comment: I think that the code you shared does **not** throw _Deprecation warning_ (I tried with moment `2.18.1` even if I don't know which is the value of `tickets` variable). Please try to understand which line throws the warning and, if you can, provide a snippet or a fiddle showing your issue.

Answer (score 1):

The implied question is 'Why am I getting this deprecation warning', and the answer is because you're making use of the moment function in a way that's deprecated and no longer officially supported.

From the link you provided:

"...moment construction using a non-iso string is deprecated. What this means is you can safely do..."

```
> moment("2014-04-25T01:32:21.196Z");  // iso string, utc timezone
> moment("2014-04-25T01:32:21.196+0600");  // iso string with timezone
> moment("2014 04 25", "YYYY MM DD"); // string with format
```

You're calling moment like this:

```
moment(value.end_date, "YYYY-MM-DD");
```

Which doesn't conform exactly to one of the strict signatures listed above, and so will be handled by the fuzzy handler that tries to resolve whatever value is passed in and return something usable, which is the functionality that's been deprecated.

You *may* be able to resolve this simply by matching the formatter exactly:

```
moment(value.end_date, "YYYY MM DD");
```

However you're also passing a Date object into moment, when it looks like it's expecting a String, so what you most likely want is to convert the Date to a string and then pass that and the correct formatter to moment.

```
moment(value.end_date.toISOString(), "YYYY MM DD");
```

or

```
moment(value.end_date.toISOString());
```

This will effectively submit something like this:

```
moment("2017-07-05T17:22:49.396Z", "YYYY MM DD");
```

or

```
moment("2017-07-05T17:22:49.396Z");
```

And this does match the expected signature and shouldn't throw the warning.